# Pentaho Zimbra Web Service (zimbra.xsd not found)

Tags: web-services, zimbra, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to implement a database integration on a system that triggers, after a user creation, a account creation on Zimbra service through ZimbraAdminService.

The server version is 8.6

On Pentaho Web Service Lookup step, when I fill the URL field with https://example.com/service/wsdl/ZimbraAdminService.wsdl and hit "Load" button, I get the following error:

```
Could not load WSDL file: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'zimbra.xsd'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found: file:/C:/Program Files/Pentaho/data-integration/zimbra.xsd
```

I already checked the documentation on https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Wsdl

Anyone faced such problem and has a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem above, I had to go to the browser, access the following addresses, load and save the XML generated of the xsd services as .xsd extension:

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbra.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraAdmin.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraAdminExt.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraMail.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraRepl.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraSync.xsd

https://example.com/service/wsdl/zimbraVoice.xsd

Put this files on /your-program-install-folder/Pentaho/data-integration (on Windows - C:\Program Files\Pentaho\data-integration)

After doing that, the problem will be solved.

Comment: The thing is that step does not solve the problem. Maybe because Pentaho Web service lookup step does not afford Zimbra web service because it seems to be more complex to Pentaho according to Matt Castters. At this moment I am trying a workaround installing and using Soap Call (a experimental step) according to the this [tutorial](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Web+services+lookup). When using the HTTP Post step it returned the message "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL".